# Python starter program : Moving files

Tags: python, macos, file, move

Looking to make some use out of Python! I wanted to write a script to move all those carelessly placed .jpg files from my desktop.

Thing, is the script I'm using doesn't seem to be finding anything.

thoughts?

```
import os, shutil, glob

dst_fldr = "~/path/Desktop/newfolder"; 

for jpg_file in glob.glob("~/path/Desktop"+"\\*.jpg"):
    print jpg_file + "will be moved to " + dst_fldr
    shutil.move(jpg_file, dst_fldr);
```

Comment: Do you have any accompanying output, error or otherwise?

Comment: @DavyM No error.... glob returns an empty list in this case and nothing to iterate over in the loop, so the script silently exits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`~` is not a character that glob understands (it's a character that bash understands and expands). You'll have to provide a full path.

```
dst_fldr = "/path/to/Desktop/newfolder";
```

In addition, you'd want to modify the wildcard search, to something like this:

```
glob.glob("/path/to/Desktop/*.jpg"):
```

If your python script resides in Desktop, you can drop the `/path/to/Desktop` part of the path in both cases.

With these changes in place, I believe you're good to go.

Comment: Wala! This works now :D Thank you very much COLDSPEED.

Any chance you know a good way for me to use glob on multiple file types? something that checks ".jpg, .JPG, ,gif," ect. I imagine I could filter with if conditions, my hope is there is something nice I can do with the search already being done

Comment: Indeed you can. Specify `/path/to/Desktop/(*.jpg)|(*.gif)`. Add more extensions as needed.

Comment: Did'nt seem to work. Ended up throwing another loop around it 

 "for jpg_file in glob.glob("../"+file_type): "

Comment: @DrewL.Facchiano Oh, my bad. I guess it isn't possible. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568580/python-glob-multiple-filetypes) though it seems what you've done is good enough.

Comment: No worries! Thanks for the help, I'm excited to have this script working :)

Comment: @DrewL.Facchiano Glad to have helped. Do consider marking this answer accepted if you feel like it. :)