# Use multiple file extensions for glob to find files

Tags: python, directory, filepath, glob, python-os

I am using glob to list out all my python files in the home directory by this line of code.
I want to find all .json files too along with py files, but I couldn't found any to scan for multiple file types in one line code.

```
for file in glob.glob('/home/mohan/**/*.py', recursive=True):
    print(file)
```

Comment: I've closed this as dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568580/python-glob-multiple-filetypes, but reopened. I think you should avoid glob in that case because it will scan directories more than once. Better compute the list of files and check patterns.

Comment: Use `os.walk()` and filter on a filename-by-filename basis. `glob.glob()` does not support multiple patterns.

Comment: use [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html): https://stackoverflow.com/a/57054058/9935654

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk), which looks in subdirectories as well.

```
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("path/to/directory"):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith((".py", ".json")): # The arg can be a tuple of suffixes to look for
            print(os.path.join(root, file))
```