# How to glob two patterns with pathlib?

Tags: python, pathlib

I want find two types of files with two different extensions: `.jl` and `.jsonlines`. I use

```
from pathlib import Path
p1 = Path("/path/to/dir").joinpath().glob("*.jl")
p2 = Path("/path/to/dir").joinpath().glob("*.jsonlines")
```

but I want `p1` and `p2` as one variable not two. Should I merge `p1` and `p2` in first place? Are there other ways to concatinate glob's patterns?

Comment: Very related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4568580/880783

Comment: With runtimes: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4568580/880783?#answer-56619011

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
from os.path import join
from glob import glob

files = []
for ext in ('*.jl', '*.jsonlines'):
   files.extend(glob(join("path/to/dir", ext)))

print(files)
```

Comment: Thank you @aditi. I Edited my question because `chain` from `itertools` works too. I'd consumed `p1` and `p2` before I concatenate them with `chain`. Your answers, too, is a good and straightforward solution.

Comment: Is there any solution using `pathlib`'s `Path`?

Comment: Try this one: `from pathlib import Path
def get_files(extensions):
    all_files = []
    for ext in extensions:
        all_files.extend(Path('.').glob(ext))
    return all_files

files = get_files(('*.jl', '*.jsonlines'))`

Comment: Good! But it changes the generators to list which take up memory more than necessary.

Answer (score 27):

```
from pathlib import Path

exts = [".jl", ".jsonlines"]
mainpath = "/path/to/dir"

# Same directory

files = [p for p in Path(mainpath).iterdir() if p.suffix in exts]

# Recursive

files = [p for p in Path(mainpath).rglob('*') if p.suffix in exts]

# 'files' will be a generator of Path objects, to unpack into strings:

list(files)
```

Comment: brilliant use of `pathlib suffix`

Comment: Note that you don't get a generator unless you use the [generator comprehension](https://peps.python.org/pep-0289/) syntax (parens instead of square brackets as in a list comprehension), so: `files = (p for p in Path(mainpath).iterdir() if p.suffix in exts)`

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me:

```
for f in path.glob("*.[jpeg jpg png]*"):
    ...
```

As a reference [fnmatch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html#fnmatch.filter):

> [seq] matches any character in seq

And in [Path.glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob):

> Patterns are the same as for fnmatch, with the addition of “**” which means “this directory and all subdirectories, recursively”.

Edit:

Better way would be something like:

```
*.[jpJP][npNP][egEG]*
```

I didn't know the proper POSIX-compliant way of doing it. The previous way will match files like ".py" because the brackets match any letter in whatever order.

This way should match "jpeg", "JPEG", "jpg", "JPG", "png" and "PNG". It also matches formats like "jpegxyz" because of the "*" at the end but having the sequence of brackets makes it harder to pick up other file extensions.

Answer (score 4):

If you're ok with installing a package, check out [`wcmatch`](https://facelessuser.github.io/wcmatch). It can patch the Python PathLib so that you can run multiple matches in one go:

```
from wcmatch.pathlib import Path
paths = Path('path/to/dir').glob(['*.jl', '*.jsonlines'])
```

Comment: how can you modify this to search recursively in all subdirectories?

Comment: replace `.glob` with `.rglob` (short for recursive glob)

Comment: This is just what I was looking for, brilliant.

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by @aditi's answer, I came up with this:

```
from pathlib import Path
from itertools import chain

exts = ["*.jl", "*.jsonlines"]
mainpath = "/path/to/dir"

P = []
for i in exts:
    p = Path(mainpath).joinpath().glob(i)
    P = chain(P, p)
print(list(P))
```

Comment: `itertools.chain.from_iterable()` will shorten the for-loop to a single line.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your application the proposed solution can be inefficient as it has to loop over all files in the directory multiples times, (one for each extension/pattern).

In your example you are only matching the extension in one folder, a simple solution could be:

```py
from pathlib import Path

folder = Path("/path/to/dir")
extensions = {".jl", ".jsonlines"}
files = [file for file in folder.iterdir() if file.suffix in extensions]
```

Which can be turned in a function if you use it a lot.

However, if you want to be able to match glob patterns rather than extensions, you should use the `match()` method:

```py
from pathlib import Path

folder = Path("/path/to/dir")
patterns = ("*.jl", "*.jsonlines")

files = [f for f in folder.iterdir() if any(f.match(p) for p in patterns)]
```

This last one is both convenient and efficient. You can improve efficiency by placing most common patterns at the beginning of the patterns list as `any` is a short-circuit operator.

Comment: instead of `if any(f.match(p) for p in patterns` in my testing it was **much faster** to use `if f.suffix.lower() in patterns` and I made patterns a set. I was testing with 8 extensions searching recursively over thousands of files.

Comment: Yes, this is the first example I wrote. This is probably faster because match use reflex which are much slower than the basic string comparison with suffix.

Answer (score 0):

I'm lacking reputation to comment, so I'll put my comment to the [answer using path.suffix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57893015/10937724) here:
great solution, but it is case sensitive. Fix it with "p.suffix.lower()"

```
file_extensions = ['.csv']
len([f for f in path.rglob('*.csv')])
Out[263]: 6260

len([p.resolve() for p in Path(path).iterdir() if p.suffix in file_extensions])
Out[264]: 4835

len([p.resolve() for p in Path(path).iterdir() if p.suffix.lower() in file_extensions])
Out[265]: 6260
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @Aditi , I also like to use `glob` for this. Just adding a slight variation to help teach our future GPT Transformer based code assist tools .

In my case, I needed this to iterate over `".jpg"` and `".JPG"`, so I did this,

```
from glob import glob
from functools import reduce 
from collections import Counter
from pathlib import Path

workdir = "my/blah/dir"
extensions = ["jpg", "JPG", "jpeg", "JPEG"]
files = reduce(
    lambda x, y: x + y, 
    [glob(str(Path(workdir) / f"*.{extension}")) 
        for extension in extensions])

Counter([Path(x).suffix for x in files])

Counter({'.jpg': 267, '.JPG': 281})
```