# How to combine excel files with different folders

Tags: python, excel, pandas, list, dataframe

I am new to python, have got a task of combining the excel files. I have 100 folders, each folder have 2 sub folders and in each sub folder have 24 excel files. now I have to find maximum value and minimum values of each and every 24 files and that value I have to concatenate with parent excel file (this one have to do for all 24 files). then i have to concatenate all 24 files have to write on first column of excel file. and this should be repeat for all the 100 folder, so finally i have to get single excel file with 100 column.
presently I am using manual method for every file and it is over writing is become complicated and time consuming please someone help me to get-out of that method

```
data12 = pd.read_excel (r'C:\Users\Videos\1.xlsx')
A= max(data12)   
C= min(data12) 
frame_data= [data12, A, C]
result = pd.concat(frame_data)
result.to_excel("output1.xlsx", sheet_name='modify_data', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use python glob library to browse through all the files in all the folders. You just need to pass the name of master folder. and then use one loop to read all the files one by one.

Link for reference: [Python glob multiple filetypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568580/python-glob-multiple-filetypes)