# I don't understand Python Solution I used to Glob multiple file types

Tags: python, python-3.x, glob, pathlib

So I need to parse and read files that have only "fip" or "frp" in them. Rather than just doing all full glob then using an if statment, I decided to search the webs on how I can achieve this. I stumbled on the answers here: [Python glob multiple filetypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568580/python-glob-multiple-filetypes?page=1&tab=votes#comment75935309_4568638)

Specifically modified my code to use a solution I found:

```
flist = [f for f_ in [odfslogs_p_handler.glob(e) for e in ('*frp*', '*fip*')] for f in f_]
```

The p_handler is a pathlib object. Now this code works. I just need some help understanding the wizardry behind it.

I know this is list comprehension but I've only dealth with simple examples. Can someone please explain to me why this works?
Also can I chain in more patterns in the inner tuples? So lets say I wanna also parse .txt, and .csv. Is it just a matter of adding a comma and including those patterns inside the tuple ?

Comment: An alternative would be the glob `*f[ri]p*`.

Comment: I didn't know glob can handle regex?. Btw, is there a way to prevent it from capturing files that are not plain text files. Like if the file has *frip.zip or *frp.csv? I want to exclude any files that are not pure text files that have the chars frp/fip in them and or the one that end in .frp and .fip. No zip files and no other file types @KlausD.

Comment: Globs do not support regular expressions, they have their own similar but very limited syntax. And no new questions as a comment please!

Comment: @KlausD. please just this one time. I don't want to open up a whole new question for this? Feel like I'd be spamming