# Glob doesn't return list of files from specified directory

Tags: python, glob

I've found two ways of listing files from a specified directory from other posts here on Stack Overflow but I can't seem to get them working. The first one returns the path and second return the files I'm looking for but also the path. I have tried several ways like renaming the target directory and files but it doesn't seem to do the trick.

The code in question:

```
import glob

jpgFilenamesList = glob.glob(r"C:\Users\viodo\PycharmProjects\pythonProject")
print(jpgFilenamesList)

mydir = r"C:\Users\viodo\PycharmProjects\pythonProject"

file_list = glob.glob(mydir + "/*.jpg")
print(file_list)
```

what I get:

```
['C:\\Users\\viodo\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject']
['C:\\Users\\viodo\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject\\dngjknfjkg.jpg', 'C:\\Users\\viodo\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject\\fjkdnfkl.jpg', 'C:\\Users\\viodo\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject\\skdklenfkd.jpg']
```

Solution found in another thread: [Python glob multiple filetypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568580/python-glob-multiple-filetypes)

Some tweaking got it running smoth. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please do not include images of code. Please copy the relevant part of your code in your question.

Comment: Sorry, edited now

Comment: You can also share the result you get, and what result you would expect.

Comment: What is the output you're trying to get? Your 2. print statement returns all files with their full path. If you only need the basename of the file you should have a look at [os.path.basename](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename)

Comment: But shouldnt glob. just return a list of the file names and not the whole path? Imma try os.path right away

Comment: glob returns a list of __[pathnames](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob)__

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glob returns a list of pathnames relative to the root directory. That root directory is assumed to be your current working directory unless the glob pattern specified is an absolute path. In short, because your pattern is an absolute path pattern, the returned files will not be relative, but absolute, including the entire path.

When not using an absolute path pattern, in some cases, you could get just a file name if a file name matches in the current working directory. That file name would of course be relative to the current working directory.

In Python 3.10, you should be able to change the assumed root directory without using an absolute pattern via a new `root_dir` parameter, but this is not currently available in 3.9 and below: https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/glob.html.

In your case, as mentioned in the comments by othes, `os.path.basename` should be able to get just the file name if that is what you are after. Alternatively, you could change the current working directory via `os.chdir` and provide a glob pattern of simply `*.jpg` and get just the file names relative to the that current working directory, both are reasonable solutions.

Extracting the base name:

```py
mydir = r"C:\Users\viodo\PycharmProjects\pythonProject"
file_list = [os.path.basename(f) for f in glob.glob(mydir + "/*.jpg")]
```

or returning the files relative to an arbitrary "current working directory":

```py
os.chdir(r"C:\Users\viodo\PycharmProjects\pythonProject")
file_list = glob.glob("*.jpg")
```

Depending on your requirements, one solution may be better than the other.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I found a solution in anther thread but this runs great too so thanks alot

Comment: Not a problem :)