# Specify multiple file extensions with glob python

Tags: python, glob

I'm reading all the image files from a folder. I want to specify different image types such as **jpg**, **jpeg**, **png**

My code:

```
for file in glob.glob("./Images/*.jpg"):
```

How could I add more types to this?

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python glob multiple filetypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568580/python-glob-multiple-filetypes)