# The code below only sees photos with jpg extension. How should I change the syntax to include photos in png,jpg,jpeg format

Tags: python, png, jpeg

The code below only sees photos with jpg extension. How should I change the syntax to include photos in png,jpg,jpeg format

```py
image_df_train_f = pd.DataFrame({'path': list(Path(input_path).glob('**/*.jp*g'))})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To list files with different extensions, you can use glob like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57054058/):

```
EXTENSIONS = (".png", ".jpg", ".jpeg")
path = [p.resolve()
        for p in Path(input_path).glob("**/*")
        if p.suffix in EXTENSIONS]
image_df_train_f = pd.DataFrame({'path': path})
```

---

**Be aware** that the solution you provided in the comments, while concise, may list unnecessary files, so you should not use it.

```
image_df_train_f = pd.DataFrame({'path': list(Path(input_path).glob("*.[jp][pn]g"))})
```

While it does list files with `.jpg` and `.png` (without `.jpeg`, by the way) extensions, it also includes `.jng` and `.ppg` files it locates in the directory.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply add more addition to the DF

```
image_df_train_f = pd.DataFrame({'path': list(Path(input_path).glob('**/*.jpg'))+list(Path(input_path).glob('**/*.png'))+list(Path(input_path).glob('**/*.jpeg'))})
```

This will solve your problem

or ====================

```
shpfiles = []
for dirpath, subdirs, files in os.walk(path):
  for x in files:
    if x.split('.')[-1] in ["shp","pdf","txt"]:
        shpfiles.append(os.path.join(dirpath, x))
```

Comment: it doesn't work but I fixed it with this code: image_df_train_f = pd.DataFrame({'path': list(Path(input_path).glob("*.[jp][pn]g"))})

Comment: that's good. or you can use the os.walk method since there might be some time you can have extensions like jpg,pdf,docx..etc.

Comment: @TamilSelvan What are the benefits of `os.walk` over `Path.glob` in this use case? You can list files with multiple extensions with `Path.glob` as OP has already done.

Comment: check the latest comment that i put , it can solve many items in a single list, instead of you want to change the RegEX for everytime

Comment: @TamilSelvan your second solution (with `os.walk`) is unreasonably long and cumbersome. Also it's better to use [`os.path.splitext`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) for getting an extension of a file.

Comment: @DemianWolf the reason to add more extensions. for example, you want to create the same for the list of 100 extensions. the REGEX won't work there. that's why I am going this way.

Comment: @DemianWolf yes you are right. we can do that much more optimistic way. i faced a lot of issues with the glob in mac. but, i started to use os.walk since it will not have any issue with different OS like windows need r"",..etc

Comment: @zeynepsert you shouldn't use glob this way (`image_df_train_f = pd.DataFrame({'path': list(Path(input_path).glob("*.[jp][pn]g"))})`), since it will list not only jpg and png files but also those with extensions like jng.

Comment: @TamilSelvan `r""` is not what `glob` needs to work on Windows. `r""` is often used for backslashes (`\`), which are used in Windows paths instead of `/` on *nix. But `glob` (Unix style pathname pattern expansion) does **not** need these. You should just use "/" instead of "\" as usually done for cross-platformity purposes.

Comment: @TamilSelvan which issues have you faced with `glob` on Mac?