# I need to delete csv an xlsx files simutaneously

Tags: python, delete-file

I am extracting data into csv and xlsxI need to delete those files simultaneously

My code :

```
Csv_files=glob.glob(os.path.join("*.csv))
xl_files=glob.glob(os.path.join("*.xlsx))
for f in csv_files:
 os.remove(f)
for f in xl_files:
 os.remove(f)
```

Instead of removing seperately,i need to delete in 3/5 line of code

Comment: What do you mean by simultaneously, and why is it important? See [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: [python-glob-multiple-filetypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568580/python-glob-multiple-filetypes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

itertools has lots of utility methods for this sort of problems

```
import itertools
Csv_files=glob.glob(os.path.join("*.csv"))
xl_files=glob.glob(os.path.join("*.xlsx"))

for f in itertools.chain(csv_files, xl_files):
    os.remove(f)
```

Comment: In what way is this simultaneous? In what way is this not separately?

Comment: No need for `chain` - `glob` returns lists so you can just concatenate them

Comment: @PeterWood i have mentioned format type twice in seperate variables and deleting the files(2 loops)..Instead of that i just want to loop though files in directory  and remove format types(In single loop it should remove directory).

Comment: @Stuart Sorry i didnt understand.New to python

Answer (score 2):

```
from glob import glob
import os
for f in glob('*.csv') + glob('*.xlsx'):
    os.remove(f)
```

Comment: Yes it worked..Thanks @kaksi...I already implemented the Previous comment.That also worked..